# UIPIckerView appears but is not the item I created in the main storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I am trying to "rework" how my picker views show and hide in my app. Some of my issue here may be that I had it working one way and now am trying to do it a different way and I do not understand the difference.  With that said:

I have created a test project to limit this to this current issue. I have a `UIPickerView`, a `Toolbar` with two `Bar Button Items`, a text field where the picker view value will be entered and a text label. I start in `ViewDidLoad` by hiding the picker and the toolbar. Then when the user taps the `textField` the `UIPickerView` and the `Toolbar` are to appear. The user selects the value then taps done to hide the picker and toolbar.

Here are my issues. When the app loads, everything appears good. Then when I tap in the text field, a grey picker appears but has no data. The toolbar does not appear though. I need the picker I put into the main storyboard to appear (no grey background) and to include the data from `dataArray` array. I need the toolbar to appear as well.  Your help is appreciated. Code is below.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var myPickerView: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet var pickerViewToolbar: UIToolbar!
@IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!

var dataArray = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    hidePickerParts()
    textField.inputView = myPickerView
    self.myPickerView.removeFromSuperview()
}

func hidePickerParts() {
    self.myPickerView.hidden = true
    self.pickerViewToolbar.hidden = true
}

func showPickerParts() {
    self.myPickerView.hidden = false
    self.pickerViewToolbar.hidden = false
}

@IBAction func cancelPickerView(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    hidePickerParts()
}

@IBAction func pickerViewDone(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    hidePickerParts()
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    showPickerParts()
    myPickerView.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return self.dataArray.count
}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return self.dataArray[row]
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    textField.text = dataArray[row]
    }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

Comment: Why not provide your test project. Better chances of getting help.

Comment: Here is a [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/929d80mh8lqacah/Picker%20View%20Test.zip?dl=0) to my zipped  project.